# F# value restriction in empty list

Tags: list, f#, value-restriction

I have a F# function:

```
let removeEven (listToGoUnder : _ list) =
    let rec listRec list x =
        match list with
        | [] -> []
        | head::tail when (x%2 = 0) -> head :: listRec (tail) (x+1)
        | head::tail -> listRec (tail) (x+1)

     listRec listToGoUnder 0
```

It removes all elements at an even index in a list. 
It works if I give the list some imput, like `removeEven ['1';'2';'3']` I get `['1';'3']` which I am supposed to. But when I insert a empty list as parameter, I get this error:

> stdin(78,1): error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'it' has been
>   inferred to have generic type
>
> val it : '_a list     Either define 'it' as a simple data term, make
>   it a function with explicit arguments or, if you do not intend for it
>   to be generic, add a type annotation.

Help, anybody?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The empty list (`[]`) is quite special; it can be a list of any type. Therefore, the compiler complains that you don't have a specific type for `[]`. Adding type annotation on the argument helps to solve the problem:

```
let results = removeEven ([]: int list)
```

*or more idiomatic type annotation as suggested by @kvb:*

```
let results: int list = removeEven []
```

This is probably beyond the question, but your function should be named as `removeOdd` since indices often start from `0` and your function removes all elements with odd indices. Moreover, things are much more clear if you use pattern matching on first two elements of the list rather than keep a counter `x` for checking indices:

```
let rec removeOdd = function
    | [] -> []
    | [x] -> [x]
    | x::_::xs -> x::removeOdd xs
```

Comment: Note that you can also add the annotation directly to `results` instead, which might be more idiomatic.

Comment: The proposed removeOdd function fails when the argument is `[]`.

I'm trying to solve this in a generic way, but I can't manage to handle the `[]` case without a "error FS0030: Value restriction".

Is it possible to make such function truly generic?